# CUDA vs Intel AVX / SSE vector sum performance questions

Tags: cuda, simd, intrinsics

First of all I'm new to CUDA and I'm trying to learn, so maybe I'm doing something wrong. I wanted to compare the CUDA performance vs the equivalent function implemented with Intel intrinsics expecting that CUDA will yield a better result.

To my surprise though, thats not what I'm seeing. My function is extremely simple, I just add two vectors and store the results in a third one. My CUDA code is as basic as it gets, in the setup function I have :

```
void cudaAddVectors(float* vectorA, float* vectorB, float* sum, int numElements)
{
//
// Allocate the memory on the device
//
float* dvA;
float* dvB;
float* dvC;

cudaMalloc((void**)&dvA, numElements * sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc((void**)&dvB, numElements * sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc((void**)&dvC, numElements * sizeof(float));

//
// Copy the host vectors to device vectors
//
cudaMemcpy(dvA, vectorA, numElements * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(dvB, vectorB, numElements * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

//
// Perform the sum on the device and time it
//
deviceSumLink(dvA, dvB, dvC, numElements);

//
// Now get the results back to the host
//
cudaMemcpy(sum, dvC, numElements * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

// Cleanup and go home
cudaFree(dvA);
cudaFree(dvB);
cudaFree(dvC);
```

}

then the device code is run either with blocks or threads, like so:

```
void deviceSumLink(float* a, float* b, float* c, int numElements)
{
    //deviceSum<<<numElements, 1>>>(a,b,c);
    deviceSumThreads<<<1, numElements>>>(a,b,c);
}
```

And the actual code running on the device:

```
__global__ void deviceSum(float* a, float* b, float* c)
{
    int index = blockIdx.x;
    c[index] = a[index] + b[index];
}
```

or

```
__global__ void deviceSumThreads(float* a, float* b, float* c)
{
    int index = threadIdx.x;
    c[index] = a[index] + b[index];
}
```

I timed the Intel version of this and the CUDA summing different size vectors and verifying that both produced accurate results. For the CUDA calls, I'm timing only the deviceSumLink call, not the memory setup and everything, but regardless of the method of invoking the kernels, the Intel intrinsics version (using 8-element arrays) is just smoking the CUDA out of the water. Basically, the Intel SIMD version of the function is something like 10x faster!

I did not expect this, so I attribute this to me being a complete newbie in CUDA. So what am I doing wrong? I thought CUDA was supposed to be much faster in those kinds of things, I think I must not be using it right or something.

If you have some insight, I'd appreciate the comments!

Thx!

Comment: Forgot to add I'm running this on a MacBookPro Retina with 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 and NVidia GeForce GT 650M

Comment: Are you saying your benchmarking is being done on arrays with *8 floats*? (ie. numElements = 8)?

Comment: numElements can be any multiple of 8, and the vectors are floats, yes. Intel wants the memory to be aligned to a 32 byte boundary so they are aligned.

Comment: That isn't what I asked. Let me try again. For the quoted "something like 10x faster!", what is the value of `numElements` that you used.

Comment: Yes, in this particular case yes...I tried with different multiples of 8 and I saw some strange results , for example, having 800 elements yielded 0.001028 milisec for intel and 0.013893 for the CUDA. Then 8000 elements had 0.009781 for intel and 0.008457 for CUDA and then 80000 elements yielded 0.105219 for intel and 0.006614 for cuda (?!) 

So, what am I missing? How come 80000 be faster than 8000 ? Thx for the help

Comment: If you make the vectors long enough, performance on this memory bound task should reflect the relative memory throughput of the two platforms. For shorter vectors, other aspects come into play: I you run the test multiple time, the CPU will be able to keep the data in L3 cache, with much higher throughput. With short vectors on the GPU, there is not enough parallelism to achieve optimal memory throughput (typically GPU memory throughput doesn't level off until vector length reaches several million elements). You may want to plot throughput at increments of 100,000 elements up to 10 million.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try again with suggested vector lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using either only 1 block or 1 thread per block to add vectors won't fully utilize the GPU. And they won't work for large vectors due the [the limitation of thread size per block and block size](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities).

To correctly add two large vectors and to get max performance, you need a kernel like this

```
__global__ void
vectorAdd(const float *A, const float *B, float *C, int numElements)
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < numElements)
    {
        C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
    }
}
```

and invoke it using the following threads/blocks settings

```
int threadsPerBlock = 256;
int blocksPerGrid =(numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;

vectorAdd<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, numElements);
```

Please refer to this CUDA sample for more details.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/#vector-addition